# Parsing message between background.js and contentScript.js fails

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My `background.js` file is:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log(response.farewell);
    console.log('ytr');
  });
//alert() it did execute the here
});
```

My `contentScript.js` is:

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log(request.greeting);
});
```

Nothing gets executed here, what could be the problem? I'm sure the problem is not caused by my `manifest.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong event.

`chrome.extension.onMessage` is deprecated, to the point of not even being in the documentation anymore.

You need to use `chrome.runtime.onMessage`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find the code that suggested `extension.onMessage`?

Comment: I forgot. sorry about that.

Comment: I put  ajax like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152988/ajax-post-cant-send-data-to-server-side in my popup.js, do u know why it doesn't work?