# Ajax() POST can't send data to server side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My js side look like this

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data: {data:'abc'},
        url: "http://example.com/",
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

in my PHP I do

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With");

    $user_id = $_POST['data'];
    echo $user_id;
```

But my result in console returned blank.

To debug, I try to `echo '123'`, the ajax did received the value of 123, what has gone wrong here?

Comment: It should work as expected as i can see it

Comment: If the receiving URL (`example.com` in your code snippet) is different in *any* way from the URL sending the request, your data will be blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). There is nothing you can do to get around this, other than using a server-side proxy. If you can (and assuming you aren't already) use a relative link

Comment: try with data: {'data':'abc'}, or data: {name:'data', value:'abc'},

Comment: `if(isset($_POST["data"])){echo $_POST["data"];}else{echo "NO POST DATA RECIEVED";}`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Good point but then how to explain `echo '123'`? Maybe this is just a browser cache issue or whatelse. Or maybe wrong debugging method

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if that is the case why can I get the 123 value from the server side?

Comment: Hmm. That is a little odd. There's no reason why one string value would work and another wouldn't. Did you receive any other error messages?

Comment: I suspect you didn't have provided all your server side code

Comment: @EltonJamie Have you clear browser cache? What if you rename `data` to something else. What about GET request? Etc... I'm sorry but i'm quite out of idea

Comment: @A.Wolff GET have the same issue. Actually I'm putting my js within a file call popup.js which I'm developing a chrome extension, maybe that's why.

Comment: inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network tab...see what is in response and status etc

Comment: @A.Wolff GET worked! omg I'm totally confused. What's wrong with POST?

Comment: It sounds like a cache issue loading external js file. Im not sure how you are testing it

Comment: Please append complete request and response headers.

Answer (score 1):

data should also be in quote

```
 $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data: {'data':'abc'},
           crossDomain: false,
            url: "http://example.com/",
            success: function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This does not cause the OPs issue.